# How to use less by "var less = require('less');"

Tags: node.js, less

It's there anyone to use "less" like this:

```
var less = require('less');
less.render('.class { width: (1 + 1) }', function (e, css) {
  console.log(css);
});
```

In my computer, it said: "Error: Cannot find module 'less'".But I had tried to install "less" by

```
"npm install less -g"
```

before use "require('less');"

Comment: Global modules can be a bit tricky some times. Try removing the `-g` at the end (which makes it a local module) and run your code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively recently NPM changed few things regarding global modules.

Now, by default, simply `require(my_module)` after installing it globally does not work, that is, NPM does not even check if the `my_module` is installed in global path.

What you have to do is two options:

1. If you still want to use global module, do `npm link less` while being in your project, that will create symbolic link to `less` installed in global path. It is often used in development, but for prodution they advice not to (as you lose version control).
2. Install module locally `npm install less` in your project folder. Works well for both development and production, but as you guessed, it downloads `less` module again.

More on this subject: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your version of Less (and node).
You can take  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/less/less.js/master/bin/lessc as an example. The docs also got a section about [programmatic-usage](http://lesscss.org/usage/#programmatic-usage).

For Less v2 you should point to `less-node` and for earlier version to `less`. Depending if you install global you should change the path in the `require`, see also [Loading from node_modules Folders](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders):

> For example, if the file at '/home/ry/projects/foo.js' called
>   require('bar.js'), then node would look in the following locations, in
>   this order:
>
> /home/ry/projects/node_modules/bar.js 
>   /home/ry/node_modules/bar.js
>   /home/node_modules/bar.js 
>   /node_modules/bar.js

Which mean you probably have to set `less/lib/less`.

Also the promise module should be installed by running:

```
npm install promise
```